# Gatsby: sharing on facebook -> image is too small

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook-opengraph, gatsby

I have a blog built with Gatsby and I am trying to add sharing functionality to the posts.

I know that facebook requires a certain size for the image to be added on top of the title in the sharing card, instead of on the side of the title.

When I check on the facebook debugger i see that the share card looks fine (big image on top of the title). You can check it here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fkeen-leakey-7a99fa.netlify.com%2Ffamous-vietnamese-fruits%2F

When i try to share the post the share card is actually smaller.

I thought it could be a problem with the `og:image:width` and `height` tag not being present in the `meta` but after adding them they don't seem to do anything.

These are some of the properties i have in my meta

```
 { property: `og:url`, content: url },
 { property: `og:type`, content: `image/png` },
 { property: `og:image:width`, content: `1200` },
 { property: `og:image:height`, content: `630` },
 { property: `og:image`, content: image },
 { property: `og:title`, content: title },
 { property: `og:description`, content: metaDescription },
```

Any idea on what could be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Facebook Crawler tries to follow your `og:url` Tag - which points to https://elingos.com - and there is no image defined - it should work when you fix the URL!

I checked it by using a [Preview Plugin](https://placid.app/social-share-preview) and then comparing that Image with the direct source!

---

**Edit - a better Way to Debug this URLs:**

Also in the Future, you can make use of the [Facebook Sharing Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fkeen-leakey-7a99fa.netlify.com%2Ffamous-vietnamese-fruits%2F) here you can see under "redirect-path" that its going to another URL :)